# Get the select value without refreshing the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

With this code I can see each option value printed but the page is refreshed every time I select an option. The server get the post data correctly, so I just need to do it without refreshing.
Thanks. Regards.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select name="day" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option>Please select a date</option>
      <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
      <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
      <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
   </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#day').change(function() 
   {
      $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: "day.php",
           data: $("form.day").serialize(),
       });
        return false;
   });
</script>
<?php 
include 'day.php'; ?>
```

day.php

```
<?php
$day = $_POST['day'];
echo $day;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the onchange to call a Javascript function that copies the data to a  hidden field in another form, and use Ajax to submit that one instead.

Optionally, you could also submit the data through Ajax directly, without the additional form, but for things that might be done with high frequency, I find it useful to minimize the bandwidth as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have an example?

Comment: Okay, I think you would in fact need Ajax for the hidden form, so that you could submit it asynchronously.

Comment: Check my comment below

Answer (score 0):

> > I think you need this:

## e.preventDefault();

//add your id="day"

```
 <select name="day" id="day" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        $('#day').change(function(e) 
           {
             e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                   type: 'post',
                   url: "day.php",
                   data: $("form.day").serialize(),
               });
                return false;
           });
```

Comment: It works but the page is still refreshing. (I added the id)

Comment: Remove this part onchange="this.form.submit();"

Comment: Try to add it to your form action="javascript:void(1)"

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: When i remove this section onchange="this.form.submit(); it's working fine try to check properly try to console.log to check the event

Comment: Check my comment below

Answer (score 0):

I could see every option value printed by the `<p id=..>` without refreshing the page. But the post data is not passed to day.php..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function postSelection(selectObject) {
        var day = window.dateForm.day.value = selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].value;
        var dataString = "day=" + day;

        $.ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url: "day.php",
        data:dataString,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#list").html(response);

        }
      });
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="displayForm">
<select name="day" onchange="return postSelection(this)">
<option>Please select a date</option>
<option value="Mon">Monday</option>
<option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
<option value="Fri">Friday</option>
</select>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="dateForm">
<input type="hidden" name="day">
</form>

<?php include 'day.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```